# NoMethodError: undefined method `sign_in_as!', FactoryGirl, Rspec, Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I am new at Rails. I'm using FactoryGirl to create users for my integration tests, and I cannot figure out how to sign in my user in the test.

My factory looks like this:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
    factory :user do
        sequence(:email) { |n| "user#{n}@ticketee.com" }
        password "password"
        password_confirmation "password"
    end

    factory :confirmed_user do
        after_create { |user| user.confirm! }
    end
end
```

And my test looks like this:

```
feature 'Editing an exercise' do

    before do
        ex = FactoryGirl.create(:ex)
        user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
        user.confirm!
        sign_in_as!(user)
    end

    scenario 'can edit an exercise' do
        visit '/'
        click_link 'Exercises'
        click_link 'running'
        click_link 'edit'
        fill_in 'Name', :with => 'kick boxing'
        fill_in 'Description', :with => 'kicking a box'
        click_button 'Save'
        page.should have_content('Exercise updated!')
        page.should have_content('kick boxing')
    end
end
```

When I run the test I get the error:

```
Failure/Error: sign_in_as!(user)
NoMethodError:
undefined method `sign_in_as!' 
for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1:0xb515ecc>
```

The app works great, it's only the test that fails. Any help would be appreciated. THanks!

Answer (score 1):

You were right, my test couldn't find sign_in_as!, and I ended up writing an authentication helper that looks like this:

```
module AuthenticationHelpers
    def sign_in_as!(user)
        visit '/users/sign_in'
        fill_in "Email", :with => user.email
        fill_in "Password", :with => "password"
        click_button "Sign in"
        page.should have_content("Signed in successfully.")
    end
end

RSpec.configure do |c|
    c.include AuthenticationHelpers, :type => :request
end
```

and sticking it in spec/support/authentication_helpers.rb. That worked.
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

where is sign_in_as! defined? It seems to me like it's defined in ApplicationController and therefore not available in your test.

You probably already have an integration test to log in your user, something like this:

```
scenario "user logs in" do
  visit '/'
  fill_in "Username", with: "username"
  ...
end
```

If that is the case you should be able to pull out most of the code into a helper method and use that in your before block

Edit:
I just now figured out you were probably using Devise, in which case you should edit your spec_helper.rb like this:

```
RSpec.configure do |c|
  ...
  c.include Devise::TestHelpers
  ...
end
```

and use sign_in instead of sign_in_as!

Comment: Yes, I am using Devise. I added c.include Devise::TestHelpers to my spec_helper file, and now the error is  Failure/Error: sign_in(user)
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `env' for nil:NilClass

Comment: I read through devise's documentation on Github http://github.com/plataformatec/devise again. In the Test Helpers segment it is stated that Devise does not provide any helpers for integration tests. The way to go seems o be creating/refactoring the "user logs in" test, like I suggested.